# "Strict" Avro Parsing Mode (No dropping additional fields)

Tags: java, scala, avro

This is tangentially related to [avro json additional field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48432732/avro-json-additional-field)

The issue I have is that JSON Avro decoding allows for additional fields on the root level recrod while disallowing them on inner records because of a parsing failure. In the current project I work on we have a requirement that we cannot drop any data which means I need to find a solution somehow.

See this code example https://gist.github.com/GrafBlutwurst/4d5c108b026b34ce83d2569bc8991b3d
(Avro 1.8.2)

Does anyone know if there's a "strict" mode for the AVRO Parser or something similar? This ticket also seems to link somewhat to it https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-2034

Thanks!

EDIT: After more researching it seems there's a PR open to fix this 
https://github.com/apache/avro/pull/321 but only for ruby

EDIT II: It most likely seems to be a parser bug it's not only in nested object but also an issue if the string contains several json objects and the first one contains additional fields. There's a `drain` method that is supposed to pop left over tokens from the stack but it doesn't seem to work. as the current parsing position is always 1 when it's entered (top of the stack) as of yet I haven't figured out why.